# How to programmatically replace PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

Is there a way to programmatically replace PYTHONPATH ?
I should add that I want to run decode.py with spark-submit

I have the following directory structure at some-path:

```
decode.py
decode2.py
crfsuite/
    crfsuite.py
    _crfsuite.so
    libcqdb-0.12.so
    libcrfsuite-0.12.so
```

decode.py:

```
import crfsuite
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tagger = crfsuite.Tagger()
```

The following command works:

```
PYTHONPATH=./crfsuite LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./crfsuite python decode.py
```

Or if I copied crfsuite/crfsuite.py and crfsuite/_crfsuite.so to my local directory (where decode.py exists), then the following also works:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./crfsuite python decode.py
```

Is there a way to programmatically add .py and .so files? I came up with decode2.py:

```
from ctypes import *
import imp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cdll.LoadLibrary('<some-path>/crfsuite/_crfsuite.so')
    imp.load_source('crfsuite', '<some-path>/crfsuite/crfsuite.py')
    tagger = crfsuite.Tagger()
```

Executing:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./crfsuite python decode2.py                                

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decode2.py", line 6, in <module>
    imp.load_source('crfsuite', '<some-path>/crfsuite/crfsuite.py')
  File "<some-path>/crfsuite/crfsuite.py", line 17, in <module>
    _crfsuite = swig_import_helper()
  File "<some-path>/crfsuite/crfsuite.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_crfsuite')
  File "sw/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/importli/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _crfsuite
```

Comment: have you tried `sys.path.add('<some-path>/crfsuite')` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it would be `append` or `insert`. `sys.path` is not a `set`, it is a `list`.

Comment: Ah, I should add that I want to run decode.py with spark-submit . Thus the motivation for doing away with PYTHONPATH

Comment: @PeterWood sorry I meant `append` of course. `sys.path.append('<some-path>/crfsuite')`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , would you like to rewrite your comment as an answer? I can then check it as the accepted answer.

Comment: would be glad too in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

`PYTHONPATH` env. variable contents is copied in `sys.path` module, so before importing you can add  some paths like this for instance:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/module")
# your_module.py will now be found in /path/to/your/module
import your_module
```

note that you can also remove paths using `sys.path.remove` if `PYTHONPATH` overrides some system lib and you don't want it to.